# How to disable firebase auto generating UUID for web in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store data from a web app made in a flutter to the real-time database, firebase. But I have an auth ID that I have generated and I want the user's data to be stored in that field named "The user's generated ID," but when I store data it isn't being stored the way I want it. It's saving in the referenced field but there is another generated id in the field and then the data is that field. It saving it like this:

This is how the data is being stored:

[image: This is how the data is being stored]

and this is how I am saving it:

```
await post(Uri.parse("https://officialnasproject-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/App/People/${AuthID}.json"), body: jsonEncode(userDataMap));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you call the REST API with a `POST` request, Firebase will (according to is [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-post)):

> `POST`: Add to a list of data in our Firebase database. Every time we send a `POST` request, the Firebase client generates a unique key, like `fireblog/users/<unique-id>/<data>`.

To specify the complete path yourself, use a `PUT` request instead of `POST`. **If** you have a `put()` function too, that'd be:

```
await put(Uri.parse("https://officialnasproject-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/App/People/${AuthID}.json"), body: jsonEncode(userDataMap));
   //
```